# Gmail Menu Button

Tags: google-apps-script

I am hoping to write a Google Script that will archive all emails that are older than some date.  And in that script I was going to add a custom button, like in Google Sheets, so that I can run my script.

Does the functionality exist in Google Script to add a menu/button to the UI in Gmail ?  If so how can I implement this?

Comment: Question is too broad.

Comment: Yes, that's clearer.

Comment: Not what you're asking exactly, but this is something you could implement with a google apps script and a time-driven event.  The event could automatically fire nightly, running the script, and you could perhaps obviate the need for a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to modify the GMail UI with Google Apps Script, unfortunately.

As an alternative, you could create a contextual gadget to put your "archive all" button on every message in your inbox. See the [Gmail Platform docs](https://developers.google.com/gmail/gadgets_overview).

Comment: Thanks for the alternative!  I'm hoping that with the next gmail/calendar UI update they may add some more functionality with scripts too.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2021, it is possible to extend Gmail UI via Google Workspace add-ons:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/gmail/extending-message-ui