# Is it possible to make an google app script with GUI for gmail and how?

Tags: user-interface, google-apps-script, gmail

In the past I've done some google app-scripts with Google Sheets and Google Docs, which are cool since they offer GUI integration with menus and side-bars, with plenty of widgets etc.

Now I'd like to do that with Gmail, i.e. I'd like to have a side-bar displaying data and widgets.

However I haven't found the way to do that and I start thinking it may not be possible.

So, is it possible to have some script with GUI on Gmail and how?

If not, what's the work around?

Comment: You'd probably need to build a Stand Alone HTML App that acted like an email program.  E.g. List emails, list sent emails, have folders, etc.  I don't know if that is considered a "work around", but that's all I can think of.

Comment: Are you referring to web apps? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Apps Script does not have this feature, like it does with Sheets and Docs. I guess only a browser extensions can tweak Gmail's interface.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gmail Menu Button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26471442/gmail-menu-button)